# PHPMailer isSMTP loading the server into timeout but working properly on localhost

Tags: php, phpmailer

**Now before you mark this question as duplicate of some other question, please consider this**

I have been reading about the problem since 2 days, and have tried various suggested solution for solving following code:

```
      public static function send($details = array()){
        require_once ('includes/emails/'.$details['file']);
            $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
            $mail->isSMTP();
            $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
            $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
            $mail->Port = 587;
            $mail->SMTPSecure="tls";
            $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
            $mail->Username = Config::get('mailer/username');
            $mail->Password = Config::get('mailer/password');
            $mail->SetFrom(Config::get('mailer/username'));
            $mail->AddAddress($details['email']);
            $mail->Subject = $details['subject'];
            $mail->MsgHTML($msg);
            if($mail->Send()){
                return true;
            }
            return false;
     }
```

now, details is an array which passes some necessary information regarding mail, and config is a class that helps me access my pre-defined values. This all is just to improve re-usability of code and send more type of emails by using same code block.

The main problem I am facing is that when I user `isSMTP()` function on localhost it takes a while and the mail is sent properly, but on my DO server, it still does send the emails BUT ends up the whole site into timeout!

I have tried using isMail and isSendmail which are some popular solutions but I do not know why they are not working for me! so isSMTP seems to be my only goto option for now.

Please help me how can I send emails from my server without server timeout! (Note I also tried, timeout function of phpmailer but not working)

Comment: You've been looking for 2 days yet somehow managed to avoid the gmail example provided with PHPMailer, have not enabled debug output so you don't know what's taking the time, have enabled exceptions but are not catching them, have not configured any error handling, all of which has been covered many times in questions on here, and in the PHPMailer docs. Your $msg variable is also undefined. The fastest way to send from PHPMailer is using SMTP to a mail server running on localhost, and that's also been covered on here and in the docs.

Comment: I did use it to see server client dialogue, I used value '3' to see if there are any errors, but everything seems fine on my localhost.. and on server there was nothing being displayed, just got timed out.

Comment: I have actually tried a lot more things like removing isSMTP, and isMail, etc. neither of the solutions work

Comment: Ohh.. the mail is being sent though, the only problem is everytime the server is getting timeout

Comment: You're not looking for just errors - you want to see exactly what is taking the time. If outbound SMTP connections are blocked on your server, then you will indeed see nothing happening - but the tests in the PHPMailer troubleshooting guide will tell you how to find out what is going wrong. Don't just change things randomly and hope - that's not debugging.